# Converting a PDF to a PNG with Alpha-layer (transparency-capable) taking way too long with my current command and options

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a particular PDF that is a combination of vector images + text into a raster image (preferrably PNG w/ an alpha layer), and it generally takes 80 seconds with the following command:

```
convert -density 300x300 "C:\im\files\pdfFile.pdf" -resize 180x180 -flatten -quality 100 -profile "C:\im\sRGB.icc" "C:\im\output\converted.png"
```

My bet is that the problem lies with the text in the file because of the font that is used -- probably causing a huge issue on the vector end of things.

Any suggestions for intermediate steps that could be used to cut the time it takes to successfully convert the file into an image?

Looking for 10 seconds or less total time, but honestly any improvement is welcomed at this point!

Here is the problematic file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0HRnSFOJFezb2RMRlktWDFpRmM

I'm not sure if this problem is going to require me to write an extension for Image Magick for a solution to this issue, or if this is more of a "I'm not 100% familiar with the tools I'm using, so someone that knows more could help", sort of thing.

Comment: Have you tried using [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com)?

Comment: Yes, and the only way I've found for it to take a reasonable amount of time was for me to use png16m as the output device -- this however doesn't support transparency. Using pngalpha as the device output yields similar results to the ImageMagick route.

I've also attempted to find a way to use the png16m output device with GS and then somehow re-introduce the transparency into that format... To no avail.

Comment: If the PDF is large, the "-density 300x300" won't buy you much other than extra time to decode it.  Also the "-quality 100" is not appropriate for PNG output.  Try omitting both and see if has any effect on the output image's appearance.

Comment: I have tried without both of those parameters -- sadly the issue isn't the output appearance - it's the length of time it's taking to get the output I want.

Thankfully I found that Inkscape actually does what is required  in a timely manner, so Ghostscript / Image Magick aren't needed at this point!

Comment: Please check and correct your post - your link doesn't work...

Comment: Why do you make a 400MB image of 2,500 x 3,300 pixels only to resize to a tiny 139x180 pixels?

Comment: Well, A) It's 44kb, not 400MB. Idk where you're getting 400MB from.
B) I'm not making an image, it's an image somebody else has uploaded and it needs to be turned into a thumbnail AND be able to be used for something else that requires transparency.

Comment: If you run `/usr/bin/time -l convert -density ...` you'll see that the PDF requires 400MB when rasterised at 300dpi. Generating 2,500x3,300 pixels is pointless when you only want less than 180.

Comment: Again, I'm not generating these files - they are user-submitted - and I don't believe having the user's file's reduced in any way is going to be an option.

Nice to know, however, that I can see how much memory is required to rasterise - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I didn't find an answer using Image Magick or Ghostscript -- the solution I found was Inkscape-related.

The issue here is that you CAN do the conversion with Inkscape without much findangling, **if** you don't *need* it to be done via the command line.

When using Inkscape, the PDF file will not be read correctly unless you use the method of importing the PDF - Poppler/Cairo import. This however cannot be done via options in the command line, so unless you go into Inkscape's Github and find a bunch of random EXE's, one of which is the "pdftocairo.exe" which will perform the function I was looking for. Using the "-png" and "-transp" options will convert the pdf into a transparency-capable .png.

**For Example:**
pdftocairo "Path\to\pdf" -png -transp "Optional\output\path" will do the trick.

**Note:** Someone else brought up the good possibility that Image Magick, when using Ghostscript to do the PDF->png conversion, could be having an issue finding the appropriate font, so it will spend time searching for one close to the target font? This would make sense since this long-conversion time seems to be linked to particular fonts, as mentioned in the original post.